# Changes of tab color - macro - does not work properly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which changes the tab colors. If there is any value in the sheet then the tab changes into green. If there is nothing then it changes into red. I combined this macro from the ready ones found on the internet. Currently I put this to ThisWorkbook but in this instance it applies to every sheet in the workbook and I wanted only those 2 sheets specified by me ("Our Data" and "Test"). I split this macro to sheets located above ThisWorkbook but then it doesn't work. Can somebody help me to amend it?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Test As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Cells.Find("*") Is Nothing Then
    Test.Tab.ColorIndex = 3
Else
    Test.Tab.ColorIndex = 10
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange2(ByVal Test As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Cells.Find("*") Is Nothing Then
    Our Data.Tab.ColorIndex = 3
Else
    Our Data.Tab.ColorIndex = 10
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't split it this way... Delete the second one and improve first as presented below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Test As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

If Test.Name = "Our Data" Or Test.Name = "Test" Then
    If Cells.Find("*") Is Nothing Then
        Test.Tab.ColorIndex = 3
    Else
        Test.Tab.ColorIndex = 10
    End If
End Sub
```

Keep it where you have it now (in `ThisWorkbook` module)

**EDIT- additional information** for all who will want to use it. Presented idea is very inefficient. The event will fire each time when any changes would be made in any of cell in any of sheet. Please consider using other events. I would suggest to use `SheetActivate` of `SheetDeactivate`.